# I'm scared of certain celestial objects

Tags: mental-health, terminology, anxiety-disorders, psychologist-psychology

I have a huge fear of photos of certain things in space. Here's a list:

- Nebula
- Galaxies
- Planets
- I am not scared of photos of stars (like the sun or distant stars), galaxy or star clusters (far away enough so the galaxies are not too large, like this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Heic1401a-Abell2744-20140107.jpg/800px-Heic1401a-Abell2744-20140107.jpg)
- I am also not scared of comets
- Asteroids are not very frightening, only a little bit

When I look at photos of these, my heart begins to race. I have a book with these photos in it and I can not look at it in bed or I fear I will have nightmares (I have had nightmares of me flying through space before).

Is there an explanation / name for a phobia similar to this?  Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see these photos? Is it possible to just avoid looking at those things?

Comment: Yes, it is not serious enough to require a doctor IMO... I was really just curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Health SE!

## Astrophobia

I did a Google search for [ `fear of space` ] and looked at what appeared. I think that your phobia is called "astrophobia". See, for example, [this Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/astrophobia).

## Causes

You can try a Google search, and look at some of the results, to learn [why phobias develop](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+phobias+develop).

## Treatment

Like all phobias, and like all other anxiety disorders, your fear is treatable. See [here](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/specific-phobias/diagnosis-treatment/treatment/txc-20253354).

If it's only a tiny problem, maybe you can treat yourself; post a new question asking how. Or you can pay a psychologist the full hourly rate to do the treatment.

If it's a bigger problem (e.g. if you're a primary-school teacher who's just been asked to teach an astronomy unit to your students), your medical insurance will likely cover the treatment. See your doctor.

## Disclaimer

P.S.  I'm an IT consultant, not a doctor, so this answer may be full of mistakes.

Comment: In my opinion, a link to a reliable source stating that Astrophobia does exist and listing a few symptoms (although the term really is self explanatory) would be sufficient.

Comment: I added a link to Wiktionary.

Comment: +1 as the answer is no perfectly suited for the question in my eyes and also for **see your doctor**. For the ones that don't believe Wiktionary, Astro phobia is also mentioned in [this article](https://collections.nlm.nih.gov/ext/dw/101315738/PDF/101315738.pdf) of 1879 according to Google, although I haven't figured out the page number yet.

Comment: @Narusan Page 11 (ctrl+f), thanks!

Comment: @Narusan: I linked to Google on purpose, because I was too lazy to read and choose a link. :)

Comment: @tealhill It is your job as an answerer though to select an eligible link. Anyone can do a google search, so don't include it in your answer if you don't want to make that choice.